# Implementing CATiledLayer on a UIWebView for fast scrolling

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, quartz-graphics

I have a big webview in my iPad app and scrolling performance seems to be a big issue, especially the first time you browse the webview. In mobile Safari, the scrolling is extremely smooth and the page simply appears as a transparent checkerboard pattern and loads in as it comes into view. From what I've read, the way to handle this is using CATiledLayer, but I have no idea how to implement this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A UIWebView should already do its own tiling behind the scenes.  There's no way to manually back a UIWebView with a CATiledLayer that I'm aware of, due to its complex rendering architecture.

If you create a UIWebView that is only the size of the display, the only reason I could think of for slower scrolling than Mobile Safari would be other overlaid views that need to be composited on the web view when scrolling.